QR Factorization Algorithm Requirements
For an application I'm working on, we must find the QR factorization of an input matrix A, and I've written a C++ function that does this using a householder approach (Gram-Schmidt is apparently not as reliable and prone to error). To prevent any segmentation faults, I want to implement some conditional checks up-front to not attempt QR factorization when it's not possible. In that case, we have an alternate solution that does not require QR factorization but is not as ideal (i.e. it's our last resort solution).
With that said, I was wondering if you guys could provide suggestions on what to check before performing this operation. It's been awhile since I've worked with QR factorization, but I dug out my old Linear Algebra textbooks and know the following. The input matrix A (an m x n matrix) must have linearly independent columns. If that is true, then the matrix A can be factored as A = QR.
How would you guys recommend efficiently checking for this in a C++ algorithm? Is there anything else that should be checked as a pre-evaluation condition?

I think you need to first define QR factorization [believe it or not there are variations] and state your goals.  Then consider an $m\times n$ matrix of all $1$s.  That matrix has rank 1 but still has a QR factorization by the standards I'd consider.  Btw checking for all columns linearly independent likely takes as long as doing QR factorization.

Please clarify some aspects of your problem.  Do you know a priori whether $m \ge n$?  What "old Linear Algebra textbooks" did you consult?  For example, Golub and van Loan, Matrix Computations (3rd edition) has Algorithm 5.2.1 (Householder QR) that assumes more rows than columns in $A$.

If you are concerned with finding the number of linearly independent columns, aka the rank of $A$, I can address that.  However this seems not connected to segmentation faults, a memory management issue.
